# Why does java accept Long format with underscore, but it doesn't parse it using String?

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

I am aware of the fact that this format `long val = 1_000_000L;` is valid in java, but what I found non constitent is the behaviour of the `Long#parseLong` method that does not parse this format if it is passed as a `String`, I tried the below code and I always get the exception:

```
   String h = "1_000_000L";
    long val = 1_000_000L;
    System.out.printf("this a valid format : %d\n", val);
    try {
        Long m = Long.parseLong(h);
        System.out.println(m);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.printf("cannot parse this number : %s\n", h);
    }
```

NB. I am building something like a personal **java compiler** and I want that it works without getting rid of the underscore format.

Comment: Haha... I have never ever used the underscores in a Java program before. Also, good luck with your personal Java compiler (why if I may ask?). I made a personal Java dialect (JavaX), but it transpiles into Java source code and then calls the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: The Long API was decided a long time ago.  You risk breaking existing programs by changing its semantics.

Comment: I would suggest learning more about tokenizers at this point of your compiler effort.

Comment: @StefanReich let's say this is for a learning issue

Comment: Check how parseLong works: https://pastebin.com/gd8hUA7e

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am familiar with this API, I'm just wondering why does the compiler accept it and the parsing methods don't

Answer (score 1):

There never was a requirement that numeric literal that you can type in source code would work the same way as numbers parsed from a `String`.

Here is the [Javadocs of `Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-):

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' (\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to
>   indicate a positive value.

So not only are underscores not allowed, but the `L` suffix also.  It's not meant to parse numbers of the format from source code.

[The underscores in numeric literals were introduced in Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html), but only to improve readability of *source code*, not programmatic parsing of strings.

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

These features are entirely separate and were never meant to be consistent with each other.

The `NumberFormatException` you got is expected and it is working correctly.

Comment: yeah thanks for your enlightenments, but I'm just wondering why did not work knowing it is a valid format according to the java compiler ?